# Can't read UTF-8 file after packaging JavaFX project

Tags: javafx, utf-8, character-encoding, package, java-io

My project has to read a text file which is encoded in UTF-8.
When I run my program in NetBeans everything is OK and the characters are read from the file correctly. But when I run my `.exe` packaged program the characters are not what they should be.

**My code:**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\sa\\shlah.txt" ));
String s = br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(
                new UTF8Reader(new FileInputStream(shlahFile)));
```

code above uses UTF8reader which do its job even when you have packaged the program.

Comment: You might went to avoid UTF8Reader as there's always  a warning that it is an internal api and may be removed in the future

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a issue with different default encodings...

Specifying the encoding to use should fix your issue. This is possible without using external libraries by using [`Files.newBufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-):

```
BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(new File("D:\\sa\\shlah.txt").toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```